# Pending edits on Stack Overflow look weird

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I tried to edit a question on Stack Overflow, and I found the following page.

[image]

It looks weird. It should have some UI, or it looks good when this message will appear in a popup when clicking the `EDIT` button rather to redirect to this blank page with a single line.

Comment: Did you open the edit link in a new tab/window, instead of just clicking it?  That should normally be a popup.

Comment: No..i just clicking on `edit` button

Comment: For users with the full editing privilege that URL would take to the editing form to override the pending edit.

Comment: The last sentence is barely comprehensible. Can you adjust it?

Comment: I got the same thing, redirected to that weird-looking page, instead of getting popup or something.